# Is "Delete this message" functionality ignored in mobile Gmail?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gmail, motorola-moto-g

I have messages threaded in both my PC's Gmail and mobile Gmail on-board my Moto G Plus / Android 6.0. Three or four days later I used "*Delete this message*" menu item in my PC's Gmail:

[image]

Yet, my mobile Gmail seems to be ignoring this fact. Up until now (four days and hundreds of mail refreshes later) I can still see two messages in my mobile Gmail and one (second deleted) in PC's Gmail.

My Inbox was refreshed many, many times since then. Either automatically or manually by me. I've received 100+ new emails since then, deleted or moved to some folders most of them and did a lot of other changes to Inbox.

Every of these changes, made on PC's Gmail, was perfectly replicated in my mobile Gmail. Every other factor or situation clearly confirms that Inbox (and other folders) in both of my devices are in perfect sync... with the exception to this single message.

Is this some kind of weird bug and "Delete this message" functionality should work in mobile Gmail as well? Or is it ignored and only full-thread deletes are replicated (i.e. I don't see "Delete this message" in mobile Gmail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting from PC using that option, did you **delete it from Bin** also?

I also found this to be not working, until you delete those from Bin as well.

Comment: 100% clear shot! I would not believe in such stupidity if I hadn't seen it with my own eyes. BTW: I can't delete a message that is already deleted to Bin folder. I had to empty entire Bin folder instead. But, still, final effect was exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's stupidity.